# Why don't the firebase rules work when I do a kreait / firebase-php operation with the service account?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

sorry for being naive. I'm a little confused about authentication with kreait/firebase-php package. I defined some rules at firebase console, like:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
     match /{document=**} {
      allow create,delete:if request.auth.uid == true;
    }

  }
}
```

The problem is that, even if I change the rule, the behavior of the services(CRUD) will work the same way. It appears that the JSON document (service account downloaded from google) has all permissions or does not require firebase rules.

In my case, I want to restrict access and database operations to users where they don't have authentication and permissions.

I am currently checking the email / password. If the request is true, the method will return a token. After that, I persist the token in CACHE and delete it when the user logs out. With each request, the middleware checks whether the token exists in CACHE. That way, it will only help me to restrict the user's access pages. How do I restrict the operation of the database (CRUD)? Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is expected.  Access to Firestore coming from code initialized with a service account will **always** bypass security rules.  Security rules **only** apply to access from the web and mobile client SDKs, and the REST API when provided with a Firebase Authentication token.

Comment: Thank you Doug Stevenson! So, my website developed with PHP does not need the rules of firebase, I understand. How do I manage user permissions? Thank you again

Comment: You'll have to build something that suits your particular needs.

Comment: Thank you! See you soon